# How to disable nvidia ion on Asus eeepc 1201NL?

Tags: nvidia, power-management, laptop, asus

It seems that my netbook consumes battery too aggressively. I've been told that Nvidia ION videocard embedded into it has 2 cores and one of them is consuming battery all the time in Linux, since it has been designed for Windows usage only, and there's no driver capable to manage it in Linux.

Is there any way to turn it off completely and use only one video core?

My distro is Debian based CrunchBang.